# How to instantiate NSViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, nsviewcontroller

My current Swift code of

```
         var appBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
         let controller: ViewController = ViewController.init(nibName:        "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.window.contentView.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.view.frame = self.window.contentView.bounds
```

is getting two errors. One is "Expected member name or constructor call after type name" and the other is "() is not convertible to 'ViewController'. For reference, ViewController is a class that inherits from NSViewController.

Both of the errors are occurring on the second line of code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

In swift you don't call `init` on classes to instantiate them. You leave out the init and just put the arguments right after the type name:

```
let controller = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

or, you shouldn't need to provide the `nibName` if it matches the name of the class:

```
let controller = ViewController()
```

Comment: And you have to pass NSBundle.mainBundle() as bundle. Documentation says nil is ok, but atm you get error message if you trying to pass nil as bundle.

Comment: @juniperi you just saved me many more hours of frustration. I was trying to instantiate an NSViewController passing nil for the bundle and I kept getting a "Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments" error. Passing NSBundle.mainBundle() fixes this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the initialization of the view controller a global constant in order for it to work throughout my app.  After racking my brain, I found that it was working locally, so making it global (putting it outside the AppDelegate class. works for me without the "nil" error)

```
//global constant
let viewController = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

    //links and loads the view to the main window
    self.window.contentView.addSubview(viewController.view)
    viewController.view.frame = self.window.contentView.bounds

    //works locally and elsewhere as long as viewController is global!
    viewController.statusField.stringValue = "TESTING"
    println(viewController.statusField)

    } 
}
```

Comment: Also bundle: nil works too with the viewController constant is global. Apple's docs are not incorrect.  This is on 10.9 anyways. nil loads the mainBundle according to the docs. and let controller = ViewController() also with it as a global with same class name.  I've tested all three.