# add custom view from nib to viewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller with a custom view area on the top, as seen in the below image [image]

I want to load a custom xib into this area and I am struggling to do so.
I created a `ABC.swift` file which is a subclass of NSView and a .xib file with the same name.
In the .xib file from the identity inspector I set the class ABC.
Then in my viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad()` I try to do the following

```
let abcView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ABC", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil) as ABC
```

I also created an outlet for the custom view in my vc
then in `viewDidLoad()`

```
customView.addSubview(abcView)
```

But this not working as abcView is of type Bool.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? What is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228362/os-x-addsubview-from-xib-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: @ElTomato i dont know how to convert it to swift 3 syntax. also i m a bit confused between the connections once has to make with the storyboard. `let abcView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ABC", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)` returns bool. How can i add this to subview ?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following Extension on `NSView` : (same as answer given by user `Accepted Answer`)

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

extension NSView {

    static func loadFromNib(nibName: String, owner: Any?) -> NSView? {

        var arrayWithObjects: NSArray?

        let nibLoaded = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: nibName), owner: owner, topLevelObjects: &arrayWithObjects)

        if nibLoaded {
            guard let unwrappedObjectArray = arrayWithObjects else { return nil }
            for object in unwrappedObjectArray {
                if object is NSView {
                    return object as? NSView
                }
            }
            return nil
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is how to use it in `loadView()` of an `NSViewController` :

```
if let loadedNavButtons: NavigationButtonsView = NSView.loadFromNib(nibName: "NavigationButtonsView", owner: self) as? NavigationButtonsView {
    // Do whatever you want with loadedNavButtons
}
```

Works in Swift 4 , XCode 9.2

Comment: Where arrayWithObjects is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, macOS only has a legacy means of bundle loading: [`func loadNibNamed(_ nibName: NSNib.Name, owner: Any?, topLevelObjects: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>?) -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1402909-loadnibnamed).

It shall pass the top-level objects of the nib in the array you supplied as the last argument:

```
var objs = NSArray()
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyScreen", owner: self, topLevelObjects: &objs)
```

Be sure to check it returned true. Otherwise it means it could not load the desired nib.

After it's loaded, the objects in the left-hand menu in the Interface Builder are available in your code. If you have a View in your nib, you can add it as a subview:

```
for obj in objs {
  if obj is MyViewClass {
    // Now we are sure that the obj is really a view of the desired class
    self.someView.addSubview(obj)
  }
}
```

Comment: so is there a better way to do what i want to do  ?

Comment: @sumesh, well, you can use the same storyboard for everything and try something like this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstoryboard/1426549-instantiatecontroller

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more compact version of answer already given

```
extension NSView {

    static func loadFromNib(nibName: String, owner: Any? = nil) -> NSView? {
        var arrayWithObjects: NSArray?
        let nibLoaded = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: nibName),
                                                 owner: owner,
                                                 topLevelObjects: &arrayWithObjects)

        if nibLoaded {
            return arrayWithObjects?.first(where: { $0 is NSView }) as? NSView
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```